# optimizing screen from phone size to tablet size android development

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I am fairly new to java and android. at the moment i am studying java at school. i just started working in this calculator just to get my hand in android developing. my problem at the moment is that when i deploy the app to the emulator (phone size 480x800) looks like Pic 001, but when i deploy it to my Kindle fire 1st gen (1024x600 i believe) looks like Pic 002. how can i make it so it look the same in every phone.

[image: Pic 001][image: Pic 002]

[XML File](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/27136243/main.xml)

Comment: You should read the documentation. E.g. [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) and [this](http://developer.android.com/training/design-navigation/multiple-sizes.html) " how can i make it so it look the same in every phone." You can't do that because all screens are different. And you should not do it because a larger screen may need a different UI than a smaller screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to have your buttons fill the entire width of your screen, put this in your tags `Button`:

```
android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1"
```

instead of :

```
android:layout_width="80dp"
```

If you want the buttons to be higher :
- In your tags `Button` change `android:layout_height="80dp"` to `android:layout_height="match_parent"`.
- In your tags `LinearLayout` which contain your buttons change `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to `android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_weight="1"`.
- In your tag `TextView` change `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to `android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_weight="X"` where X is the value that gives you the right proportions.
You will have a warning telling your that nested weight are bad for performance but it's the only way I know to do this.
In general, if you want a component to fill the empty space, set the width or height to 0dp and add a weight. The weight will define the proportions of the elements which want to fill the space.

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks, this help me allot. it now take all the empty space from left to right no matter what size is the screen.